# Render UI in shiny after query from user

Tags: r, shiny

I'm working with a shiny app that gets a `query` from the user, runs some `code` from another script and renders the UI. Here's what i'm trying to do:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(h1(paste("Your query is:",keyword))),
    fluidRow(h1(paste("The results were:",keyword/10)))
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observe({
      query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
      if (!is.null(query[['keyword']])) {
        source("code.R")
      }
    })
  }
)
```

I've been searching and fount the `renderUI` function, but it does not work for me.

Here's what i've tried:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    uiOutput("UI")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

output$UI <- renderUI({
        observe({
          query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
          if (!is.null(query[['keyword']])) {
            source("code.R")
fluidRow(h1(paste("Your query is:",keyword))),
    fluidRow(h1(paste("The results were:",keyword/10)))
          }
        })
      }
    )})
```

any ideas how to solve it?

Just to make myself clear: i need to wait for the user to query something, then save the query string, run analysis on it with another code and show the UI with values from the analysis.

Comment: How is the query provided to the `shiny`?

Comment: trough URL: for example http:://www.myip.com/?keyword=queryString